# Custom free shipping calculated rate cost in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am having an issue with applying this filter at checkout. the below code works as expected on the cart page, the labels for the shipping methods each update if the specified criteria (in this case "free_shipping") are met.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'my_custom_shipping', 100, 2 );

function my_custom_shipping( $rates, $package ) {

    $percentage = 0.01;

    foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {

        $test_method_id = $rates[$key]->method_id;
        if ( $test_method_id === "free_shipping" ){
            $surcharge = ( wc()->cart->cart_contents_total + $rates[$key]->cost ) * $percentage;
            $rates[$key]->label .= " Fee: {$surcharge}";
            $rates[$key]->cost += $surcharge;
        }
    }



    return $rates;

}// Function END
```

while this works fine on the cart page (but only with debug mode active, nothing loads when debug mode is turned off which is very frustrating), on the checkout page the changes do load briefly ( i can scroll down and see them ) but they are quickly overwritten with the original labels. I cannot seem to figure out why, I thought setting the filter to call later might help but it does not seem to.

all the data is there and I can output and see it but it simply does not apply in a permanent way at checkout, why would this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really get an initial cost for "free shipping" rate as there is not any cost field for "Free shipping" method in backend.

But you can add a calculated cost and change the label (differently):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_rates', 100, 2 );
function custom_shipping_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    $cc_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    $percentage = 0.01; // 1%

    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ){

            // Calculation
            $surcharge = $cc_total * $percentage;

            // Set the new Label name
            $rates[$rate_key]->label .= ' ' . __("Fee", "woocommerce");

            // Set Custom rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = round($surcharge, 2);
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

[image]

> **You should need to refresh the shipping caches:** 
>   1) First this code is already saved on your function.php file. 
>   2) In Shipping settings, enter in a Shipping Zone and disable a **Shipping Method** and "save". Then re-enable that **Shipping Method** and "save". **You are done.**

---

**Update:** *(Force clearing shipping methods from WC_Session)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_rates', 100, 2 );
function custom_shipping_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    // Reset session
    WC()->session->set('shipping_for_package_0', array('package_hash' => ''));

    $cc_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    $percentage = 0.01; // 1%

    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ){

            // Calculation
            $surcharge = $cc_total * $percentage;

            // Set the new Label name
            $rates[$rate_key]->label .= ' ' . __("Fee", "woocommerce");

            // Set Custom rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = round($surcharge, 2);
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It could works…

Comment: I can only get this to work if I have debug mode active. otherwise nothing fires and the display does not update. do you know of a way to force it to fire whenever there is a cart change? or the cart total updates? anything will do if I can force a fire of the filter. I can add a fee to cart that auto-updates easily enough. I was hoping to use this so that the charge is seen as a shipping specific fee for our API to understand. but it's inability to update regularly is a drawback that frankly makes it unusable.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/19169

this link shows issue

Comment: I input your code directly and tested with debug mode off and nothing changes. that is the primary issue I have with this filter; it does not seem to fire properly/predictably

Comment: If I have debug mode inactive and input your code directly nothing happens. the labels all remain the same. If I remove the free shipping restriction so it can apply to any shipping method, it still does not change the display of any of the methods labels or shipping cost values.  I even input a simple echo into the beginning of the function and it looks like the filter isn't even being called. I will continue to test what you have put in here. I am surprised that nothig happens...this seems like code that should simply run smoothly.

Comment: @Eolis Here is this code running [**on my test server**](http://www.cbleu.net/sites/tie2/shop/) …**try it** please… I don't have this problem on it *(and I have never had any kind of, since WC 2.6+)*… So may be The thing is to reset the session in the function at start: **I have maid an update at the end**, Try it again (I hope it will work). The issue can be related to some other customizations, plugins or your theme too…

Comment: I have tested to no avail; I will try again tomorrow and reply. I must be missing something. perhaps something obvious that a long day is making me overlook. thanks for the assistance; I will mark this resolved tomorrow when I resolve it and understand the issue.